# California Apartment squeaky whistling carpet

Tags: california, rental-property, property

I have carpet that makes a whistling/squeaking sound, everytime I walk on the living room . My apartment manager refuses to have someone inspect, to see if it's just loose floorboard, loose screw, or maybe concrete issue. I am not sure if its deemed unlivable, but its very annoying, anytime I walk across the living room, 100 times a day.

Does California Law in San Diego require property managers to fixing squeaky/whistling carpet? The carpet is stable and solid by itself.

Follow up question: if apartment manager does not want to fix, and I offer 100% of repair cost to fix it with my own money to contractor for labor/materials, given job only requires fixing a screw, are they required to fix? I find it silly for them not to.

Comment: Given how common squeaky floorboards are in...well, anything with floorboards, I'd be shocked if that were enough to deem it unlivable, unless maybe it were *really* bad.

Comment: Hi @RyanM I added follow up question above thanks